# R - grepl with a specific exclusion

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I was wondering how I can insert a specific exclusion pattern in a `grepl`.

Let us imagine, I want to seach for `WHAM`.

```
vec = c("WHAM VIDEO", "WHAM RAP", "WHAM", "HOTELNEWHAMP")
vec[grepl("WHAM", vec )]
```

What I get is

```
[1] "WHAM VIDEO"   "WHAM RAP"     "WHAM"         "HOTELNEWHAMP"
```

I can see that `HOTELNEWHAMP` is foreign.

How can I then `vec[grepl("WHAM", vec )]` and indicate clearly I do not want `HOTELNEWHAMP` ?

(not this `vec[!grepl("HOTELNEWHAMP", vec )]` because of course my real vector include many more variables).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use word boundaries.

```
vec = c("WHAM VIDEO", "WHAM RAP", "WHAM", "HOTELNEWHAMP")
vec[grepl("\\bWHAM\\b", vec )]
# [1] "WHAM VIDEO" "WHAM RAP"   "WHAM"
```

or

```
vec[grepl("(?<!\\S)WHAM(?!\\S)", vec, perl=TRUE )]
# [1] "WHAM VIDEO" "WHAM RAP"   "WHAM"
```

Comment: great answer thank you. But how can I target a specific word than I am aware of ?

Comment: don't know what you mean by the above comment.

Comment: sorry I mean that there is actually some words I would like explicitely to exclude. There is another example I am working with the word `news` and I would like to explicitly exclude some of them like `world news` but not `news of the world`. Hope I am more clear. thanks for your help !

Comment: `(?<!world )news` . ask a new question with an clearcut ex and expected output.